# VLCMobileKit iOS crash on screen lock on iPhone 4

Tags: ios, video-streaming, vlc, rtsp, libvlc

I am facing a strange issue in MobileVLCKit for iOS.I am playing RTSP links in my app. I have set the flag to play audio and video in background to true in my app. So when the app goes in background the video playing in my VLC player keeps playing without any problem.
But on iPhone 4 (with iOS 7.0.4) when I lock the screen of my iPhone when the video is playing, the app crashes without showing any logs. Strange thing is that if I send the app in background by pressing home button then the app doesn't crash. The issue is only on iPhone 4 and not on iPhone 5.
Have somebody come across such issue before?

Bellow is device crash log:

```
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI kernel[0] <Debug>: 019323.846533 wlan.A[400] AppleBCMWLANNetManager::updateLinkQualityMetrics(): Report LQM to User Land 100, fAverageRSSI -69
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::setBacklightEnableGated 0 (set level to 0x1c8)
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleMultitouchN1SPI: updating power statistics
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI kernel[0] <Debug>: ALS: AppleARMBacklight::handleMessageGated - framebufferState -> 0
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI backboardd[28] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI SpringBoard[34] <Warning>: [MPUNowPlayingController] Not registered for now playing notifications. Ignoring call to -unregisterForNotifications.
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI backboardd[28] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI MyApp[817] <Warning>: log: applicationWillResignActive
May 27 03:18:41 My-iPhone-VI MyApp[817] <Warning>: log: applicationDidEnterBackground
May 27 03:18:42 My-iPhone-VI profiled[818] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service starting...
May 27 03:18:42 My-iPhone-VI ReportCrash[819] <Notice>: ReportCrash acting against PID 817
May 27 03:18:43 My-iPhone-VI ReportCrash[819] <Notice>: Formulating crash report for process MyApp[817]
May 27 03:18:43 My-iPhone-VI com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.My.MyApp[0x19d8][817]) <Warning>: (UIKitApplication:com.My.MyApp[0x19d8]) Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
May 27 03:18:43 My-iPhone-VI backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.My.MyApp[0x19d8]' exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11
May 27 03:18:43 My-iPhone-VI mediaserverd[46] <Warning>: Encountered an XPC error while communicating with backboardd: <error: 0x3cd9f744> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x3cd9f9dc> { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }
}
May 27 03:18:43 My-iPhone-VI ReportCrash[819] <Notice>: Saved crashreport to /var/mobile/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MyApp_2014-05-27-031842_My-iPhone-VI.plist using uid: 0 gid: 0, synthetic_euid: 501 egid: 0
May 27 03:18:53 My-iPhone-VI profiled[818] <Notice>: (Note ) profiled: Service stopping.
```

Below is the stack trace taken in method **didEnterBackground:**

```
 Stack trace : (
0   MyApp                           0x0010a191 -[MyAppAppDelegate applicationDidEnterBackground:] + 76
1   UIKit                               0x2fc85543 <redacted> + 590
2   UIKit                               0x2fc06ae1 <redacted> + 764
3   UIKit                               0x2fc06721 <redacted> + 72
4   UIKit                               0x2fc6bb3d <redacted> + 664
5   GraphicsServices                    0x320a270d <redacted> + 608
6   GraphicsServices                    0x320a22f7 <redacted> + 34
7   CoreFoundation                      0x2d4599df <redacted> + 34
8   CoreFoundation                      0x2d45997b <redacted> + 346
9   CoreFoundation                      0x2d45814f <redacted> + 1398
10  CoreFoundation                      0x2d3c2c27 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 522
11  CoreFoundation                      0x2d3c2a0b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
12  GraphicsServices                    0x320a1283 GSEventRunModal + 138
13  UIKit                               0x2fc66049 UIApplicationMain + 1136
14  MyApp                           0x001078e9 main + 116
15  libdyld.dylib                       0x37d26ab7 <redacted> + 2
)
```

Comment: Post log debugger output and stack trace of this error. It can not be that there aren't any logs. Start the app from the Xcode send to the background and lock the device.

Comment: @rckoenes: I updated the answer with device crash log.

Comment: @rckoenes: I have added stack trace to the question.

Comment: @Yogi I have the same issue you described here, have you solve your problem?

Comment: @brianLikeApple: This is reproducible in VLC's native iOS app. I did not get any solution for it. You may ask **feepk** for the same as he is lead developer of VLC

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable video decoding prior to entering the background state. Otherwise, MobileVLCKit will try to draw OpenGL contents in the background which will be prevented by the OS by terminating the app.

You can disable video decoding by setting the current video track on your media player instance to -1. Once your app is moved to the foreground again, switch it back to the currently decoded video track (so you should cache it if your stream includes more than one video track).
When disabling video decoding, audio decoding is not affected and will continue just fine. This approach also got the benefit of saving CPU load and battery.. ;)

This is how VLC for iOS works, too. :)

Comment: Hi,Thanks for always being there. I tried the thing you mentioned. I set `self.objGlobalVLC.currentVideoTrackIndex=-1` in `applicationWillResignActive:` and again set `self.objGlobalVLC.currentVideoTrackIndex=-0`in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`. But that doesn't resolve the issue. Interestingly, the exactly same issue is getting reproduced in VLC  app from VideoLAN which is live on app store when I am playing RTSP links in it.

Comment: I have added stack trace to the question.

Comment: Also now after coming back from the background app is not streaming in other devices also. i.e it didn't crash but stopped streaming. Calling **play** method also didn't work.

Comment: @feepk I have tried this but with no luck. Could you please give us more details?Thanks

Comment: The new release of MobileVLCKit library have fixed this problem

Answer (score 0):

i think You need to disable video decoding prior to entering the background state,this will work for sure this is major thing Apple says that a fix for the home screen crashes is coming also you can read here more [How to take a screenshot on iphone without using lock button](http://getinfolist.com/2014/04/07/take-screenshot-iphone-without-using-lock-button/)

Comment: Thank You. I will try this and let you know the result soon.